# Skewed distributions: choosing the median or average

Tags: distributions, mean, dataset, median, weighted-mean

**Goal:**

To determine whether to use the `median` or `average` (or a weighted combination of the two) from a data set based on whether its distribution is `skewed` or `uniform`.

**Details:**

Seen below is a sample taken from economists forecasts/estimates of a financial release. There are 7 estimates in total, the statistics of which can be seen in the "*Summary*" panel along with a graph of distribution on the right hand side.

[image]

**Q1.** Based on the distribution graph and the statistics observed under "*Summary*", it seems that maybe the distribution is skewed to the right. As such, would it be a better choice to use the `median` value of 90 instead of the `average` value of 87.57?

**Q2.** The `standard deviation` of 6.00 seems to be high- should this be considered also when choosing whether to use the `median` or the `average`?

**Q3.** In cases where the `median` and `average` are much closer together, say 87 and 88 respectively, would the distribution be said to be "*uniform*"?

**Q4.** Could it ever be worthwhile constructing a `weighted average` of the two numbers, based on the distribution (let's say if it is not uniform, like in this case)? If so, does anyone have any ideas of some sort of weighting rule, or should both values *always* be multiplied by 0.5 e.g. `(87.57 * 0.5) + (89 * 0.5)` ?

Apologies if my wording or theory is incorrect in any of the above, as well as for the low-res image.

Comment: Weighted average of mean and median no interpretation.  The best summary is the entire dataset, i.e., a rug plot or empirical cumulative distribution function.

Comment: Thanks @FrankHarrell for your response. Unfortunately being new to statistics I don't quite understand your answer. If possible, would you be able to break this down for a beginner?

Comment: Often, completely different considerations determine whether to use a mean, median, or other summary, because these measure specific properties of the distribution and in your application at most one of them (typically) is relevant or useful.  Could you explain why you are permitting an analysis of skewness to decide which is the relevant statistic?

Comment: @whuber thanks for your reply. For some context, these analysts forecast are all attempting to estimate a particular news release, which consists of one "storage" number published by a governing body at a set time. Most of the time in this industry, it seems one forecast value is used to compare against this published "storage" number. For this reason, I am trying to determine in this case whether to use the median or the average to compare the published number at its release time and thought skewness would help me do so.

Comment: The answer ought to depend on your loss function: what does any particular (forecast, actual) pair cost you or your audience or clients or stakeholders?  Probably little when the forecast is close to the actual and more as they grow far apart.  Exploring this quantitatively provides insight and valuable information for deciding how to make a comparison.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that often the best summary is just to show the raw data.  If you need a 3-number summary think about using the 3 quartiles.